# Plugin - get reference to passed object

Tags: jquery, plugins

i'm trying to create my first jQuery plugin.
i got a prototype function called myListview and want to apply the plugin (named initLV) to it.

the function:

```
function myListview(div)
{
    this.div = div;
    $(this).initLV(); // apply the plugin
}
```

as you can see, i'm passing the whole prototype object to the plugin.
my question: how can i access the object's div from inside the plugin?
here's my plugin code - the 1st alert works, but all others dont :/

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.initLV = function () 
  {
    alert($("tr",this.div).length); // works
    alert(this.div.html());         // don't work
    alert($(this.div).html());      // don't work
    alert($(this).div.html());      // don't work
  }
})(jQuery);
```

it just makes no sense that the 1st alert works and the others don't.
what could be wrong?

Comment: why do you use this.div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `div` is only a field of what the `this` is. What `div` contains. If it contains an html element, so for instance you should use `alert($(this[0].div).html());` instead. But it's better to use Dan Herbert's answer that demonstrates the correct way of writing a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're a bit confused with how jQuery plugins work. A jQuery plugin allows you to perform actions on a jQuery object. It looks like your code creates a custom object, and then tries to "jQuery-ify" it. I don't think your first function even works as valid jQuery. I think it just happens to work because jQuery is good about ignoring invalid arguments.

It would help if I knew what your ultimate end goal was, however I think you might want to try something like this instead:

Your function:

```
function myListview(div)
{
    $(div).initLV();
}
```

Your plugin

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.initLV = function () {
        // "this" will be a jQuery object storing your 
        // div, or whatever else the jQuery object 
        // contains when it gets called.
        alert($("tr", this).length);  // works
        alert(this.html());           // works
        alert(this.find("tr").html());// works
    }
})(jQuery);
```